# js worker and websql database on phonegap

Tags: javascript, database, cordova, worker

i have a problem with worker and database on phonegap

my main.js open database and perform staff(create table , insert data), it's work fine , in main.js i call a worker

in worker.js i must use my database so i do

```
db = openDatabase('kpi', '1.0', 'dashboard kpi', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

I do that because i can't passe object database to my worker.

when i run my code i have this error :

```
[Error] unable to open database, version mismatch, '1.0' does not match the currentVersion of ''
```

i don't understand why it does not want open my database in my worker, i have not change my database version ....

Answer (score 1):

var worker=new Worker("js/uga_db_worker.js");

```
    worker.postMessage(ugaName);

    worker.onmessage=function(event){


        }

    };
```

it my call in main.js

i have find a fix, if in my worker i do not use a number version for opendatabase, all is working

```
db = openDatabase('kpisselencro', '', 'dashboard kpisselincro', 5 * 1024 * 1024);
```

the version number is empty, i don't know why , but it seem really fix it.

Comment: Version numbers are an issue... so most recommend avoiding them.

Answer (score 0):

How your are calling worker.js in inside main.js , opendatabase method will not have any problem if you are defining in different js.

Can you please provide code snippet how you are calling this ?

Comment: var worker=new Worker("js/uga_db_worker.js");
    
        worker.postMessage(ugaName);
        
        worker.onmessage=function(event){
         
                
            }
            
        };

it my call in main.js

i have find a fix, if in my worker i do not use a number version for opendatabase, all is working 

    db = openDatabase('kpisselencro', '', 'dashboard kpisselincro', 5 * 1024 * 1024);

the version number is empty, i don't know why , but it seem really fix it.